# How do I remove `\choose` error?

Tags: equations, amsmath

This code

```
\begin{equation}
    \sum_{j=1}^{Max\_out}{M' \choose j}.
\end{equation}
```

Produces an error:

```
Package amsmath Warning: Foreign command \atopwithdelims;
(amsmath)                \frac or \genfrac should be used instead
(amsmath)                 on input line 229
```

The odd thing is that there is no such error outside the equation. This error occurs only in the equation.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The deprecated command in LaTeX is `\choose`. It can be replaced by `\binom` here:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \sum_{j=1}^{\text{\ttfamily Max\_out}}\binom{M'}{j}.
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]